# UISlider for AVAudioPlayer error, crash the app

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

i am creating an app which includes a list of audio and when click on audio it will pass to another view-controller and that view contains an imageview, a play and pause button and a slider. But i am getting errors in adding a slider to adjust/change duration of the audio i mean change time interval by using the slider.  My code is here.

```
import UIKit
//used for audio files
import AVFoundation

class ShowStuffViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate 
{

var myText = "" //no longer needed

var myLabel = ""

var myImage = ""

//outlet for the label
@IBOutlet var showLabel: UILabel!

//outlet for the image
@IBOutlet var showImage: UIImageView!

// jukebox variable tied to AVAudioPlayer
var jukeBox: AVAudioPlayer?


//outlet for slider that controls duration
@IBOutlet var durationControl: UISlider!


//when stop button presssed, stops playing song
@IBAction func stopAudio() {
    if let player = jukeBox {
        player.stop()
    }
}

//when play button pressed, plays song according to label
@IBAction func playAudio() {
    if(myLabel == "audio1")
    {
        playMe(theSong: "naat1")
    }
    else if(myLabel == "audio2")
    {
        playMe(theSong: "naat2")
    }
    else if(myLabel == "audio3")
    {
        playMe(theSong: "naat3")
    }
    else if(myLabel == "audio4")
    {
        playMe(theSong: "naat4")
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    //displays the myLabel into the label
    showLabel.text = myLabel

    //displays myImage into the image view
    showImage.image = UIImage(named: myImage)

    //plays song according to what the label reads
    if(myLabel == "audio1")
    {
        playMe(theSong: "naat1")
    }
    else if(myLabel == "audio2")
    {
        playMe(theSong: "naat2")
    }
    else if(myLabel == "audio3")
    {
        playMe(theSong: "naat3")
    }
    else if(myLabel == "audio4")
    {
        playMe(theSong: "naat4")
    }
    else if(myLabel == "audio5")
    {
        playMe(theSong: "naat5")
    }
    else if(myLabel == "audio6")
    {
        playMe(theSong: "naat6")
    }
    durationControl?.maximumValue = Float((jukeBox?.duration)!)

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
// this function does all of the work for loading audio
func playMe(theSong: String) {

let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: 
theSong, ofType: "mp3")!)   
    // the "do" instructions set everything up to play
    do {
        try jukeBox = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        jukeBox?.delegate = self
        jukeBox?.prepareToPlay()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("audioPlayer error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // this line tells the jukebox to play!
    if let player = jukeBox {
        player.play()
    }
}


// action for slider volume control
@IBAction func adjustduration(_ sender: Any) {

    jukeBox?.stop()
    jukeBox?.currentTime = TimeInterval(durationControl.value)
    jukeBox?.prepareToPlay()
    jukeBox?.play()    
}
}
```

Comment: when does it crash on launch or when 'adjustduration()' is called?

Comment: Try setting the maximum value like 'durationControl!.maximumValue = Float((jukeBox?.duration)!)' . Also, put a print statement before this for the Float((jukeBox?.duration)!) to make sure its not nil.

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: and a red sign in front of class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {  (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT)

Comment: When? Upon launch of the VC or when the button is pressed?

Comment: no when i click the slider to change the duration then it crash

Comment: It will be best if you can put breakpoints and see which statement crashes...
also @IBAction func adjustduration(_ sender: Any) what is ibaction here....if it is value changed its an issue, because it will called everytime slider is shifted even a little

Comment: It crashes because you don't understand how == operator works. You are comparing a label to a string. The comparison always returns false.. then you are increasing the duration and boom.

Comment: ok Brandon so how to do that

Comment: Add a print statement inside the function to see if it crashed as it is called

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to update the progress of the audio player when the value of the slider is changed

```
  @IBAction func seekAudioToTime(_ sender: UISlider) {
    if let player = self.audioPlayer?.player {
        let seekTo = sender.value
        let duration = Float(player.duration) * seekTo
        if seekTo < sender.maximumValue {
            self.audioPlayer?.player!.currentTime =  TimeInterval(duration)
            updateProgress()
        }
    }
  }

  func updateProgress() {

    if let currentTimeValue = self.audioPlayer?.player?.currentTime {
        let elapsedTime = (Utilities.sharedInstance.stringFromTimeInterval(currentTimeValue as! String))
        self.timeElapsedLabel.text = elapsedTime

        if let totalDuration = self.audioPlayer?.player?.duration {
            let timeRemaining = totalDuration - currentTimeValue
            let remainingTime = "-" +(Utilities.sharedInstance.stringFromTimeInterval(timeRemaining as! String))
            self.timeRemainingLabel.text = remainingTime
            guard let isPlaying = self.audioPlayer?.player?.isPlaying else {
                print("invalid audio player state")
                return
            }
         }            
    }

}
```